# Single quotes return unexpected character

Tags: php, mysql, database, special-characters

In my table description field value is:

Alva’s Institute of Engineering & Technology (AIET)

while retrieving these field value it return :

Alva�s Institute of Engineering & Technology (AIET).

I think single quotes (') charcter is not recongnizing properly, How can I solve this Problem???

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read the [tourguide](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask questions the right way and how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're echoing this out manually by writing the text simply do

`Alva\'s..`

Alternatively, if this is coming from a database you can add:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

into the header where your other php code sits.

Comment: it's working... thank you so much..

Comment: No problem at all. If you're satisfied with the answer please mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: in view page its working..but how can i omit these characters while insertion? Im uploading data into table as csv format (bulk upload)...I try many codes but didnt got any best solution :
htmlentities(iconv("cp1252", "utf-8", trim(str_replace(array("’","'"),"&#39;",$data[0]))), ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8");

Answer (score -1):

```
$con=mysqli_connect("my_host","my_user","my_password","my_db");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
```

If your are using MySQLi extension, try mysqli_set_charset method.